# MVC modal popup

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, modalviewcontroller

I am trying to implement a modal in my application and it seems I have tried several examples that I have found - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/092589/implementing-modal-pop-up-in-mvc-application/ , https://codemagik.wordpress.com/2015/04/07/render-mvc-partial-view-inside-bootstrap-modal-dialog/, and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yrTszHY-mQ are just some and it seems I cannot even get the examples to work. Currently I have in my first View

```
<div>
<div class="col-md-3>">
    <h2>Reports</h2>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="anchorDetail" >Daily Requested Burns</a>
</div>
```

```
@section scripts
{

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var TeamDetailPostBackURL = '/Home/DateSearch';
$(function () {
    $(".anchorDetail").click(function () {
        debugger;
        var $buttonClicked = $(this);
        var options = { "backdrop": "static", keyboard: true };
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: TeamDetailPostBackURL,
            datatype: "json",
            success: function () {
                debugger;
                $('#myModal').modal(options);
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
            },
            error: function (error) {

                alert("Dynamic content load failed. - " + error );
            }
        });
    });

    $("#closbtn").click(function () {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    });
});

</script>

}
```

My Modal View

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id='myModal' class='modal'>
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div id='myModalContent'>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                               <div class="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dissmiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Daily Requested Burns Date Search</h4>
                               </div>

                               <hr />
                               <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BurnStartDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                                     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BurnStartDate, new { @id = "BurnStartDate" })
                                                     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BurnStartDate)
                                                 </div>
                                           </div>
                                           <div class="form-group">
                                                      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BurnEndDate, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                                                 <div class="col-md-10">
                                                       @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BurnEndDate, new { @id = "BurnEndDate" })
                                                       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BurnEndDate)
                                                 </div>
                                           </div>
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                   <button id="btnSubmit" name="Command" value="Submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicons-camp-fire"></i>&nbsp;Submit</button>
                                   <button id="btnClose" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-dissmiss="modal">Close</button>
                              </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My DataSearch includes a `HttpPost`

```
   public ActionResult DataSearch()
    {
        //Render the partial view to be loaded in the modal dialog
        RequestedBurn requestedBurn = new RequestedBurn();
        requestedBurn.BurnStartDate = DateTime.Now;
        requestedBurn.BurnEndDate = DateTime.Now;

        return PartialView("_DateSearch", requestedBurn);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DateSearch(FormCollection form)
    {
        // Process the post back data from the view
        string startDate = form["BurnStartDate"].ToString();
        string endDate = form["BurnEndDate"].ToString();
        //return View("DailyBurns");

        return RedirectToAction("DailyBurns", "RequestedBurns", new { startDate = startDate, endDate = endDate });
    }
```

Comment: When you debug this, how exactly does it fail?  Is that AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  Is the code executing in that `success` callback?

Comment: I don't get a response. It goes to the AJAX error function and gives me the alert "Dynamic content load failed. - Object object" which I think has to do this the `datatype: "json"`

Comment: That means you're getting an error back from the server.  What is that error?  (That is, what's in the `error` variable?)

Comment: can you show the action /Home/DateSearch?

Comment: I have updated my question with my Action. Looking at it I don't have an error variable.

Comment: can you place a break point in action DataSearch() to check if its getting there or not

Comment: It doesn't get to it

Comment: @EthelPatrick: If you can tell us what the response is from the server and what's in that `error` variable in the AJAX callback then we might be able to help you.  The system is providing you with information about the problem, don't ignore that information.